# Snooze local Notification

Tags: iphone, ios4, notifications, alarm, uilocalnotification

I am working on an alarm application and I am using local notification for that. Now I want to add snooze functionality to my alarm. I searched on Google and found that iPhone doesn't support such functionality.

But is there another way to do this?

Comment: 'I searched on Google and found that Apple doesn't...' this is funny, isn't it?

Comment: @jv42:Can you please explain?

Comment: Google is the main competitor to Apple in the smartphone business...

Comment: really funny:D.I thought it's something related to grammer...Can you help me regarding my problem

Comment: nope, else I'd have posted an answer ;)

Comment: Hi Yogi, did you manage to do this? I am looking for similar thing!

Comment: @AppleDeveloper:I used bambam2174's solution.Couldn't get any better way.

Comment: Thanks. Me too implemented same!

Comment: Glad to know that it helped...Please update the answer if you get anything better.

Comment: @Yogi would you get solution for this? i m searching tis from last 3 days

Comment: @Aaaaa: No...Still going with the workaround. Please do share if you get any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK you can't add a custom behaviour when the notification windows pops up.
BUT...
You can try it like this:
after the user has clicked "View" and the app is launched by an UILocalNotification, 
you could open a modal view with a huge button "Snooze" and another (smaller) one "Open".
And if the user taps "Snooze" you just schedule another local notification and close the app.

What about that?

---

PS: A couple of days ago I've worked the first time with these local notifications.
I had to design a class which can be used universally. 
A method for implementing snooze would be cool! 
I'll write you again, if I get a better solution. 
But please tell me (and other) in this forum, If you have found a good solution.

Comment: I am also using the same method...will,definitely update you if found something better:)

Comment: If you want to be troublesome.... schedule multiple alarms or a repeating alarm, one for 5 minutes, one for 10 minutes, another for 15 minutes, etc.  Each separated by your snooze interval.  Then, when you finally get the 'all right shut up already' from the user, pear into the future and cancel all the previously scheduled notifications before they alert.  This makes snooze essentially the default action, instead of the other way around.

Comment: Hi Bambam, did you find any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Read This articles:

1. [About Local Notifications and Push Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)
2. [Local Notification Sample Code (OS 4.0 only)](http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2010/04/local-push-notification-sample-code-os.html)
3. [Repeating an iOS local notification](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/9/13/repeating-an-ios-local-notification.html)
4. [Local Notifications](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/core-services/local-notifications.html)
5. [iPhone Tutorial: Scheduling Local Notifications using a Singleton class](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-scheduling-local-notifications-using-a-singleton-class/)

I think you can user Local Notifications for your alarm application ...

Comment: What you suggest here is to schedule repeating notifications. This is not what he's trying to do. Snoozing is a missing feature, and solutions are always hard to find ...

Comment: You want to create something like standard alarm application on iPhone ?

Comment: I don't. Probably @Yogi does! :D I think he's looking for something like a standard alarm, snoozable.

Comment: @ ViTo Brothers Apoyan:Yes,it should be a snoozable alarm.

Comment: @ ViTo Brothers Apoyan:I gone through the articles suggested by you but couldn't find explanation for snooze functionality.