# iOS: Timer or Local Notification for everyday repetitive action

Tags: ipad, ios5, nstimer, uilocalnotification

I want to display multi-buttons alertview to user everyday twice a day. They can take an action or snooze the action. If they snooze the action then the same alertview will appear again after 10 minutes. Could anyone please tell me what should be the best way to implement this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Local notifications are what you want here. NSTimer only runs while your application is running, which won't (always) be the case.

See this discussion [Snooze local Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197840/snooze-local-notification) for further information.